# Python pkgutil.walk_packages not returning subpackages

Tags: python, package

I have a package layout:

```
scenarios/
    __init__.py
    X/
        __init__.py
        Y/
            __init__.py
    Z/
        __init__.py
```

I have executed

```
import scenarios
pkgutil.walk_packages(scenarios.__path__, scenarios.__name__ + '.')
```

But this generates a list only including the packages X and Z, Y is missing. What can I use to get all the sub directories?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Here is a theory:  The walk_packages function attempts to import each module listed.  When it gets to the sub-package "Y" it attempts to import it, but there is an error.  By default, this error is suppressed.  A sideeffect is that the walk_packages function doesn't recurse into Y.  You can test this theory using the "onerror" keyword argument.  For example:

```python
import sys, pkgutil
from traceback import print_tb

def onerror(name):
    print("Error importing module %s" % name)
    type, value, traceback = sys.exc_info()
    print_tb(traceback)

import scenarios
pkgutil.walk_packages(scenarios.__path__, scenarios.__name__ + '.', onerror=onerror)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise it was failing silently on import errors. My problem was that my package wasn't on my sys.path

Answer (score 0):

This works in Python 3.6 at least, for what it's worth.  Set up the test scenario:

```sh
mkdir -p scenarios/X/Y scenarios/Z
find scenarios -type d -exec touch {}/__init__.py \;
```

Now run a version of your example code:

```py
import pkgutil
import scenarios
for module_info in pkgutil.walk_packages(scenarios.__path__, scenarios.__name__ + '.'):
    print(module_info.name)
```

Which prints:

```
scenarios.X
scenarios.X.Y
scenarios.Z
```

Comment: Despite Python >= 3.3 supporting [implicit namespace packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3) that don't require an `__init__.py`, I found that they are required in order for `pkgutil.walk_packages` to successfully recurse into subpackages