# Python does not recognize a module which is set by PYTHONPATH

Tags: python

I've searched for some time to find a solution to this problem but have come up dry. I'm hoping I can find some help here. As the title suggests, python is not recognizing a module that has been set in my `PYTHONPATH`.

I'm currently working on a project that has the following overall structure:

```
base
├── util
│   └── logging_utility.py
└── project
    └── app
        ├── config.py
        └── runner.py
```

This is executed in python 3.5 via a virtual environment called `venv_1`. I use a Mac running El Capitan.

My `runner.py` script calls the `logging_utility` using the following import statement:

`from util.logging_utility import method`.

When executing, I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'util.logging_utility'
```

I am running this in the terminal from the `base` level of the directory. I'm using the following command to call the script:

```
PYTHONPATH=$HOME/base VIRTUAL_ENV=$HOME/.virtualenvs/venv_1 PATH=$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH $HOME/.virtualenvs/venv_1/bin/python -- project/app/runner.py
```

Now, I've tried to debug this by printing out my `env` as well as `sys.path`. In both cases, the `base` directory appears in the path. So why on earth am I receiving this error?

I've also tried to update the import statement to `from base.util.logging_utility import method` which gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'base'
```

Any idea why this is happening and how I can correct this?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [Billy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7007605/billy) and [Moinuddin Quadri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2063361/moinuddin-quadri) whose suggestions solved the issue. For some reason I still needed to add the `__init__.py` files. Even though python 3.3+ supports implicit imports, looks like it was still needed. This solved the problem.

Comment: How was Python installed? Through the Python desktop installer or Anaconda?

Comment: Put an empty `__init__.py` file in your `util`, `project` and `app` directories to make them Python packages.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac it was installed using Homebrew.

Comment: ...although I don't think that will fully solve your problem, since in python 3.5 it should implicitly treat your `util` directory as a `namespace package`:  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=namespace%20package#namespace-packages...

Comment: @Billy I was under the impression python3.5 [no longer requires](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37140173/4942372) the `__init__.py` file. Is that not correct?

Comment: @Marto, yes, it was merely a suggestion since you probably should still use the `__init__.py` file so you're not inadvertently invoking a complex feature of the language.

Comment: Now that would be a slight problem. You see, Homebrew and MacPorts have their own PYTHONPATH preset.

Comment: @Billy you were correct. for some reason I still needed to add the `__init__.py` files. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might not be having the path to package in your `PYTHONPATH`. In order to add that, do:

```
 import sys
 sys.path.append('/absolute/path/to/base')
```

---

Since from Python 3.3, you do not need the `__init__.py`.

For the older version, the other possible reason is missing `__init__.py`. If you do not have a `__init__.py` file present in the directory, you can not import files of that directory.

As is mentioned in the [Packages Document](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.

Comment: I thought `__init__.py` is [no longer needed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37140173/4942372) in python 3.3+.

Comment: you were correct. for some reason I still needed to add the `__init__.py` files. This solved the problem.

Comment: for anyone going insane why you can't import despite adding your module directory to PYTHONPATH with `os.environ`, named function `__import__` doesn't look for paths in PYTHONPATH. They are added to `sys.path` once python is executed.