# How do I check if a directory is a python package?

Tags: python

If I want to check whether a directory is a python package, is it enough to check whether a directory contains a `__init__.py` file?

Comment: @vaultah Really? The `__init__.py` is no longer required?

Comment: Is there any reason you could not do the "ask forgiveness not permission" thing here? So you would go `try: from foo import bar` and `except: ...`

Comment: @RoyPrins I'm writing a command line tool to treats a directory as a project for my tool and I need to find the directories in there that python packages, so my tool know which packages it can use. Trying to import every directory seemed a bit unsafe since I could accidentally import a package with the same name as a non-package directory.

Comment: I'm adding the project root directory at the front of sys.path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before Python 3.3, only directories containing `__init__.py` files were considered packages (see [*regular package*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-regular-package) in Glossary).

Since the addition of [*namespace packages*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-namespace-package) in Python 3.3, *every* directory is a Python package, technically.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html):

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages

## Update

Based on the answer here:  [Is __init__.py not required for packages in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3)
You can see that it's no longer a requirement.