# Python dynamic import methods from file

Tags: python

I have multiple files with a structure like a file `example.py`:

```
    def initialize(context):
        pass


    def daj_omacku_teplu(context, data):
        pass


    def hmataj_pomaly(context, data):
        pass


    def chvatni_paku(context, data):
        pass


    def mikaj_laktom(context, data):
        pass
```

and I need to be able to dynamically import methods from "example.py" in a different python file like:

```
    for fn in os.listdir('.'):
       if os.path.isfile(fn):
           from fn import mikaj_laktom
           mikaj_laktom(example_context, sample_data)
```

For multiple reasons, I can not change the structure of `example.py` so I need to make a mechanism to load methods and evaluate them. I tried to use `importlib` but it can only import a class, not file with only methods defined.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: you could import your source file as module object

Comment: Try this `from example import method_name`

Comment: Amit, I need to import file dynamically based on string filename.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the exact input specification should be here, but either way there is a much better canonical duplicate available. I've linked them both for now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python `import` does not support importing using paths, so you will need to have the files accessible as modules, see ([sys.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)). Assuming for now that your sources are located in the same folder as the main script, I would use the following (or similar):

```
import sys

def load_module(module):

    # module_path = "mypackage.%s" % module
    module_path = module

    if module_path in sys.modules:
        return sys.modules[module_path]

    return __import__(module_path, fromlist=[module])

# Main script here... Could be your for loop or anything else
# `m` is a reference to the imported module that contains the functions
m = load_module("example")
m.mikaj_laktom(None, [])
```

The source files can also be part of another package, in which case you will need an `__init__.py` in the same folder with the `.py` files (see [packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)) and you import with "mypackage.module" notation. (Note that the top level folder should be in your path, in the above example this is the folder containing "mypackage")

---

UDPATE:

- As pointed out by @skyking there are lib that can help you do the same thing. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)
- My comment on `__init__.py` is outdate since things have changed in py3. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48804718/3727050) for some more detailed explanation

Comment: Actually python do sopport importing using paths: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Comment: @skyking True via libs (imp which is now deprecated and importlib for py3). I think these are also based on `__import__ `. I can add the link in a note. What I meant by "does not support" is that you cannot do `import /my/file`. Maybe I should rephrase that to "Python `import` does...".

Answer (score 4):

You were on the right track with `importlib`. It can be used to load modules by name, however I do not think you can load them into the global namespace in this way (as in `from module import function`). So you need to load them as module objects and call your required method:

```
import glob, importlib, os, pathlib, sys

# The directory containing your modules needs to be on the search path.
MODULE_DIR = '/path/to/modules'
sys.path.append(MODULE_DIR)

# Get the stem names (file name, without directory and '.py') of any 
# python files in your directory, load each module by name and run
# the required function.
py_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(MODULE_DIR, '*.py'))

for py_file in py_files:
    module_name = pathlib.Path(py_file).stem
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    module.mikaj_laktom()
```

Also, be careful using `'.'` as your `MODULE_DIR`, as this will presumably try to load the current python file as well, which might cause some unexpected behaviour.

Edit: if using Python2, you won't have `pathlib` in the standard library, so use

```
module_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(py_file)[1])[0]
```

to get the equivalent of `Path.stem`.