# Where to do package imports when importing multiple python scripts?

Tags: python-3.x

This might have been answered before, but I could not find anything that addresses my issue.

So, I have 2 files.

```
|
|-- test.py
|-- test1.py
```

test1.py is as below

```
def fnc():
    return np.ndarray([1,2,3,4])
```

I'm trying to call test1 from test and calling the function like

```
from test1 import *
x = fnc()
```

Now naturally I'm getting `NameError: name 'np' is not defined`.

I tried to write the import both in test and test1 as

```
import numpy as np
```

But still, I'm getting the error. This might be silly, but what exactly I'm missing?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Adding `import numpy as np` in *test1.py* fixes the error.

Comment: @Georgy, when I'm running using cmd what you said is working fine.. But is there a limitation when using Jupyter for the same?

Comment: Jupyter Notebook/Lab you mean? I don't understand how the presented example is applicable to Jupyter. As you accepted the answer below, does it mean that the issue is resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Python module has it's own namespace, so if some functions in test1.py depends on numpy, you have to import numpy in test1.py:

```
# test1.py

import numpy as np

def fnc():
    return np.ndarray([1,2,3,4])
```

If test.py doesn't directly use numpy, you don't have to import it again, ie:

```
# test.py

# NB: do NOT use 'from xxx import *' in production code, be explicit
# about what you import

from test1 import fnc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = fnc()
    print(result)
```

Now if test.py *also* wants to use numpy, it has to import it too - as I say, each module has it's own namespace:

```
# test.py

# NB: do NOT use 'from xxx import *' in production code, be explicit
# about what you import

import numpy as np 
from test1 import fnc


def other():
    return np.ndarray([3, 44, 5])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result1 = fnc()
    print(result1)

    result2 = other()
    print(result2)
```

Note that if you were testing your code in a python shell, just modifying the source and re-importing it in the python shell will not work (modules are only loaded once per process, subsequent imports fetch the already loaded module from the `sys.modules` cache), so you have to exit the shell and open a new one.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for explaining. It was really helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. And please do yourself a favor: do NOT use star imports (=> "from somemodule import *"), really (except of course in a python shell - and even then it might lead to unexpected results).

Comment: Sure. No one told me that before. But definitely, I'll keep that in mind. :)

Comment: This is in pep08: "Wildcard imports (from <module> import *) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools" (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) - and I can testify that they do indeed confuse the reader AND easily break your code in rather unexpected ways.

Answer (score 0):

mostly you need to have  __init__.py   in the directort where you have these files
just try creating **init**.py  file like below in the directory where you .py files are present and see if it helps.

```
touch __init__.py
```

Comment: I'm sorry.. But it did not help. Can you give any references?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks for correcting but in the question it is said that, tried "import numpy as np" files test1.py and test.py i couldn't undestand why?  i read in the document that if we trying to import local ".py" we need to have __init__.py , though i am not very sure about, so i used "mostly" in the answer, i checked in my machine  following works fine  "from test1 import *
x = fnc()

print(x) "

Comment: @ShivYaragatti  `__init__.py` are required in python 2.x to turn a directory into a package. This has changed in Python 3 (cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3). In both cases, they are not required to import a _module_ (simple .py file) - the only requirement here is that the directory containing the module is in the `sys.path`.  But anyway: the error message posted by the OP - "NameError: name 'np' is not defined" - has nothing to do with importing the `test1.py` module itself.