# Why does my python import statement fail when I import this function from outside the directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Simple example:

File structure is:

```
test/lib/f1.py
test/lib/f2.py
```

File contents:

```
$ cat lib/f1.py 
from f2 import bar

def foo(a):
  print(1+bar(a))

$ cat lib/f2.py                                                                                                   
def bar(a):
  return a
```

So `f1.py` defines `foo`, which relies on `bar`, defined in `f2.py`.

Now, loading `f1.py` works just fine when inside `test/lib/`:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from f1 import foo
>>> foo(1)
2
```

However, when loading from outside `test/lib/` (say from `test/`), this fails with an import error:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lib.f1 import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pymod/lib/f1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from f2 import bar
ImportError: No module named 'f2'
>>> Quit (core dumped)
```

Moving the code from `f2.py` in `f1.py` fixes the issue, but I don't want to do that.

Why am I getting this error and how can I avoid it?

Comment: You need an `__init__.py` file (it can be empty but it needs to be there) in `test/lib` - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages

Comment: `PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/tmp/pymod/lib python3`, and then type your code in the interpreter console. Or modify the *f1.py* import to `from .f2 import bar`.

Comment: @Craicerjack Good thought, but it doesn't fix the issue. Also, I thought `__init__.py` was optional?

Comment: @HenryHenrinson you learn something new everyday. It seems you are correct - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3

Comment: @CristiFati Doing `from .f2 import bar` does fix the issue, but it causes a new one. I can no longer do `from f1 import foo` when starting python from inside `lib`. Is there no way around this?

Comment: @HenryHenrinson: Try: `from pymod.lib.f1 import foo`.

Comment: Were you able to run the scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Define the folder where it should look for the modules:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('test')

from lib.f1 import foo
```