# Why does from . import not work in this scenario?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand relative imports in python (python3), and the following simple piece of code does not work. I would like to know what's missing in my understanding of relative imports.

I have a directory structure like this:

```
example/
   a.py
   b.py
```

a.py has the following code:

```py
def test_print():
   print("test")
```

and b.py has the following code:

```py
from . import a

a.test_print()
```

When I run b.py, I get an `ImportError: cannot import name 'a'`. However, if I go one level above (`cd ..`), and run `python -m example.b`, it runs without any errors.

Comment: The folder `example` doesn't seem to be a package. Try putting an empty `__init__.py` file in there

Comment: You can just use `import a` as it is within the same directory. Further, `from .` will not work as `example` is not a package.

Comment: @rdas, you don't need that from python3.3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Agreed, however, the `from ... import ...` statement needs an `__init__.py` file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56301295/1898437).