# In python 3.6 onwards, do we still need to use the __init__.py file to make python treat a folder as package?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have read that there is no longer a need to add the `__init__.py` file in latest versions of python to treat a folder as package. However, the python official documentation does not say this - for example the below still shows examples and documentation using the `__init__.py` file.

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat directories
>   containing the file as packages.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Do we still need to use the `__init__.py` file to make python treat a folder as package? And are there any advantages/disadvantages to adding/removing this file?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand it all, but "namespace packages" don't need it whereas "regular packages" do, https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#namespace-packages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is \_\_init\_\_.py not required for packages in Python 3.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3)

Answer (score 3):

That is True but only for namespace packages.

> There are currently three different approaches to creating namespace
>   packages:
>
> 1. Use native namespace packages. This type of namespace package is defined in PEP 420 and is available in Python 3.3 and later. This is
>      recommended if packages in your namespace only ever need to support
>      Python 3 and installation via pip.
> 2. Use pkgutil-style namespace packages. This is recommended for new packages that need to support Python 2 and 3 and installation via both
>      pip and python setup.py install.
> 3. Use pkg_resources-style namespace packages. This method is recommended if you need compatibility with packages already using this
>      method or if your package needs to be zip-safe.

Maybe you mention the [native namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages).