# How to solve "unresolved import" and "unable to import" messages in Python projects?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module, warnings, python-import

I opened a directory (on WSL Ubuntu) with VSCode with the following structure:

```
.
├── .vscode
│   ├── launch.json
│   └── settings.json
├── src
│   └── polls
│       ├── aiohttpdemo_polls
│       │   ├── db.py
│       │   ├── main.py
│       │   ├── routes.py
│       │   ├── settings.py
│       │   └── views.py
│       ├── config
│       │   └── polls.yaml
│       └── init_db.py
└── ve_websocket
```

I'm getting the warning message `unresolved import ...` when importing a file located in the same directory that the one calling it. Example: for `routes.py`

```
from views import index

def setup_routes(app):
    app.router.add_get("/", index)
```

I'm getting `unresolved import 'views' Python(unresolved-import)`. Hence *IntelliSense* for `index` function does not work.

However IntelliSense suggests this notation:

```
from polls.aiohttpdemo_polls.views import index
```

with it the `index` function is recognized for IntelliSense now and no warning message appears, but when saving the file I get this error message `Unable to import 'polls.aiohttpdemo_polls.views' pylint(import-error)` now.

So I cannot run this script:

```
[polls]$ python init_db.py
```

My `settings.json` file has this configuration:

```
"python.pythonPath": "ve_websocket/bin/python3.8",
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintPath": "pylint",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1:** *settings.json*

The solution is about using [absolute imports](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) (suggested by IntelliSense), and it is necessary to work with PYTHONPATH environment variable, so we need to add these lines to `settings.json` file for our workspace.

```
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
},
```

After that, we open the terminal (from VSC) and need to confirm the changes, then reopen the terminal and we can run the script without errors, however VSC IDE still shows error marks on `from` keywords, overlook them, because objects being imported are recognized by IntelliSense with all their properties, and you can run your scripts without any problem.

**SOLUTION 2:** *sys.path*

The problem with the previous solution is that it works only when you are using the terminal from VSC. Hence you can use `sys.path` in every script needing to import objects. Example, for my `init_db.py` file:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(str(Path.cwd().parent))

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData

from polls.aiohttpdemo_polls.settings import config
from polls.aiohttpdemo_polls.db import question, choice
...
```

Comment: You should also add `__init__.py` files to your directories to make them packages so you can then do relative imports, e.g. `from .views import index`, otherwise you won't be able to reference any code outside that package/directory.

Comment: That was my first thought but I discarded it because I had errors when running the script. Furthermore, empty `__init__.py` files are not needed since [Python 3.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3).

Comment: I wouldn't say `__init__.py` "files are unneeded", as leaving them out means you have a namespace package instead of a standard package and their semantics are subtly different in potentially important ways.