# "Package init file not found (or not a regular file)" - error when building sdist for namespace package

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, setuptools, python-packaging, namespace-package

I have a namespace package with folder structure as:
CompanyName\DepartmentName\SubDepartmentName\PkgName

Python 3.3 onwards supports namespace packages so I have not place the `__init__.py` files in the following folders:

```
CompanyName
DepartmentName
SubDepartmentName
```

In the setup.py I have place the following piece of code `setuptools.find_namespace_packages()` instead of  `setuptools.find_packages()`.

When I try to build the sdist, using the following commands:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
python setup.py sdist
```

I get the following error:

```
package init file 'CompanyName\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
package init file 'CompanyName\DepartmentName\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
package init file 'CompanyName\DepartmentName\SubDepartmentName\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
```

I have the task setup as part of azure devops pipeline's command line task and have set 'Fail on standard error' to true. The pipeline fails due to the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Though `Package init file not found (or not a regular file)` is more like a warning than an error locally, it will cause the build pipeline to fail if you set `Fail on standard error` to true when using VSTS.

Locally:

[image]

VSTS with `Fail on standard error` to default false:

[image]

VSTS with `Fail on standard error` to true:

[image]

1.For this, you can choose to turn-off the option(`Fail on standard error`) cause the python namespace package can be generated successfully though that message occurs. So in this situation, I think you can suppress that message.

2.Also, another direction is to resolve the message when generating the package. Since the cause of the message has something to do with your definitions in your `setup.py` file, you should use `setuptools.find_namespace_packages()` like [this document](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages) suggests.

*Because mynamespace doesn’t contain an **init**.py, setuptools.find_packages() won’t find the sub-package. You must use setuptools.find_namespace_packages() instead or explicitly list all packages in your setup.py.*

**In addition:** It's not that recommended to remove all `__init__.py` files in packages, check [this detailed description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48804718/10910450) from **AndreasLukas**: *If you want to run a particular initialization script when the package or any of its modules or sub-packages are imported, you still require an **init**.py file.*

Comment: In the setup.py I have already placed the following piece of code setuptools.find_namespace_packages() instead of setuptools.find_packages(). This does not solve the issue.

Comment: Hi friend, what's the result if you use `find_namespace_packages(include=['DepartmentName.SubDepartmentName.Package.*'])`. Can the warning go away?