# Is the __init__.py really not necessary for python 3.7 packages?

Tags: python, testing, package, python-3.7

Recently I created a flask application and decided to add a test folder outside the application folder (both the app and test folders are in the same directory). All the implementations I would be testing for are contained in packages and modules created in the app folder.

Having the __init__.py file in both folders work just fine as expected. However when I remove the __init__.py file from the test folder, I start to experience moduleImportError. Python doc says that the __init__.py file is no longer a requirement for packages in python 3.3+ but in my case here, seems it's a requirement. Can someone explain why it's so?

Comment: Perhaps this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3

Comment: No it doesn't. The answer there says when the \__init__.py file is empty it could be removed. In my case I had import errors and was debugging for hours until I decided to add the empty \__init__.py file in the test folder and that solved the problem.

Comment: might be a tough ask, but could you prepare a [mcve]?

Comment: @Mazimia actually the answers on that question say that `__init__.py` is sometimes required, even empty ones, even in newer versions of Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is \_\_init\_\_.py not required for packages in Python 3.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3)

Answer (score 13):

Quick answer, Yes, thanks to the [Implicit Namespace Packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) you dont need `__init__.py` files anymore.
But some tools of the standart library including [unittest](https://bugs.python.org/issue35617) or [setup tools](https://packaging.python.org/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/) still needs `__init__.py` files.

In most of the case I recommend the following project arborescence:

```
setup.py
src/
    mypkg/
        __init__.py
        app.py
        view.py
tests/
    __init__.py
    foo/
        __init__.py
        test_view.py
    bar/
        __init__.py
        test_view.py
```

Top pakage `src` and root folder does not needs `__init__.py` files.
Every other submodules need a `__init__.py` file.

By following this rule most of tools succesfully discover modules including unittest, pytest and setuptools.

Comment: If some tools like pytest and unittest still needs the \__init__.py file then it's not totally correct to say it's not necessary for packages anymore.