# Some questions about __init__.py

Tags: python, module

enviroment: python3.8

directory:

```
test\
    module1\
           __init__.py
           mod1.py
    module2\
           mod2.py
    main.py
```

---

### 1. I can import a directory without `__init__.py` , why?

I want to check how exactly **init**.py work, so I import the `module1` and `module2` in `main.py`

```
# test\main.py
from module1 import mod1
from module2 import mod2
```

In my expectation, line2 should occur error, because I didn't create `__init__.py` in `module2`

But both of them can be imported.

Now, I'm confused about how exactly `__init__.py` work

---

### 2. I can't import those package which is imported in `__init__.py`

I try to import `mod1.py` in `main.py` in this way:

```
# test\main.py
import module1
module.mod1.mod1_print() # mod1_print() is a function which is defined in mod1.py
```

So I import `mod1.py` in `test\module1\__init__.py` :

```
# test\module1\__init__.py
import mod1
```

But when I execute `main.py` I got this error:

```
D:\>"C:/Program Files/Python38/python.exe" d:/test/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/test/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import module1
  File "d:\test\module1\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mod1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod1'
```

My question is:

If I want to import `mod_print()` in this form: `module.mod1.mod1_print()` , what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37140173/9822 - python >= 3.3 dropped the requirement for `__init__.py`.
2. You could try something like this in `module1/__init__.py`:

```py
import module1.mod1
```

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.3+ has [Implicit Namespace Packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) that allow it to create packages without an `__init__.py` file.

> Allowing implicit namespace packages means that the requirement to provide an **init**.py file can be dropped completely, and affected portions can be installed into a common directory or split across multiple directories as distributions see fit.