# PyCharm does not see packages within the same namespace as current project

Tags: python, pycharm

Lets assume I have opened project I am working on as `project/some_package`. The problem is that in namespace `some_package` I have installed some another projects within the same namespace. PyCharm can not resolve origin of those modules - even if interpreter does it well.

Example

My project:

```
.
└── project
    └── some_package
        ├── main.py
        └── some_file.py
```

Site packages:

```
.
└── some_package
    ├── lib_one
    └── lib_two
```

Then in `main.py` (which interpreter gets well) but on imports from site packages pycharm raises "can not find reference"

```
from some_package.some_file import something  # <---- local

from some_package.lib_one import *  # <---- from site packages
from some_package.lib_two import *  # <---- from site packages
```

Comment: Check the working directory, I guess since it sees it as a folder there it tries to import the folder and not from site packages, try to run the interpreter from the same working directory and you should see the same problem.

Comment: It is very similar to the circular import errors, just that the file is replaced by the folder.

Comment: Right click on that directory and select `Mark Directory as > Sources Root`.

Comment: @UriyaHarpeness interpreter gets it well from any directory

Comment: @mx0 no difference - still the one from site packages is not visiable by pycharm

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your python packages as "Namespace Package" if you want to split sub-packages across multiple directories

See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48804718/5384400
- https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/