# Python Module Installation from Folder

Tags: python, module, directory, pip

I downloaded a project and am running through and installing all dependencies. At first I had errors regarding `No module named utm` and `No module named paho`. I solved these issues by going to C:\Users\me and using `pip install paho-mqtt` and `pip install utm`. Easy enough.

I then have this line `"from mfa_msgs import Mission, WaypointList, MissionControl, ControlCommand, Status"` and am getting a `No module` error here. `mfa_msgs` is a folder found in the project I downloaded that contains the Mission, WaypointList, etc. files. Where do I need to put the `mfa_msgs` folder in order to be able to access them?

Appreciate your time!

Comment: First, you should run this from the folder where `mfa_msgs` folder is located. Second, you might want to try adding `__init__.py` file in the folder alongside the `mfa_msgs`.

Comment: `__init__.py` is not required for Python version > `3.3`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I am running the script in the same folder where `mfa_msgs` is located, and there is a `__init__.py` file in `mfa_msgs` as well