# Why does python require that I import from the file above the main package directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following folder structure:

```
<project_name>

|__ <docs>

|__ <configs>

|__ <src>

.....|__  __init__.py

.....|__  utils.py

.....|__ <feature1>

..........|__ __init__.py

..........|__ feature1.py
```

where names enclosed in triangle brackets are folders.

From within `feature1.py`, I want to import `utils.py`. Since `src` is the highest level folder with an `__init__.py` file, I would have thought that that would be the package, meaning that I would need to do:

`from src import utils`

This does not work, and gives the error:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'src'
```

However, when I run

`from project_name.src import utils`

it works fine. As I understand it, `project_name` is not a package, since it has no `__init__.py` file. Why is this required, and is there a way to get it to recognise `src` as the package?

Comment: _"As I understand it, `project_name` is not a package, since it has no `__init__.py` file"_. That's not true anymore. See [Is `__init__.py` not required for packages in Python 3.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3/37140173#37140173)

Comment: Thanks. I read this, but it isn't then clear why project_name is a package, and not the folder above it, which is my Dropbox folder.

Comment: How are you running your python commands? Are you in project_name or elsewhere? What does `sys.path` give you?

Comment: `project_name` may not be a package, but it may be a directory in your Python path that the import system will *look* in for packages.

Comment: @astrochun I am running the code from within feature1 (that is, I am running feature1.py which contains the import statements).

sys.path does indeed seem to include Dropbox (which contains) project_name. I'm happy to considre this question answered.

Comment: Great. you probably had it pass through your PYTHONPATH environment variable. If you ended up using my below answer, could you mark it as the accepted one? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It really comes down to how you install "project_name". Your setup.py can tell it where the packages are.  Then `__init__.py` in each sub-folder will allow for it to be index.

An alternative approach is to use relative explicit path in your script.

`from .. import utils`

Keep in mind that the first `.` refers to `feature1` so two dots goes to the `src` path.