# Again, relative import in Python + issue with sudo

Tags: python

I have read plenty of documentation (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) and linked references) on this, but it is simply too difficult for my simple mind: I cannot understand the logics of python `import` and I usually waste plenty of time in random attempts till I reach a working permutation of settings and commands. May be this is due to the fact that I usually use PyCharm, where everything magically work. Now I am using Visual Studio Code on a remote machine and I need to ask here since I have wasted double the time I usually spend on this without reaching a permutation that works.

Using python 3 on linux (remote machine). The python interpreter is configured with a virtual environment and it does not correspond to the system level one.

I have this project. Its folder structure is mirrored in linux filesystem, i.e., prj, src, commonn, etc. are all folders.

```
prj
 |- src
 |  some py files
 |  |- common/
 |     - common1.py
 |     - common2.py
 |  |- pipelines/
 |     - main_pipeline1.py  (<- file prefixed with main_ have a __main__ entry point)
 |     - main_pipeline2.py
 |  | - other py module 
 |  | - other py module, ... and others - some of these modules use common
 |- data/ ...
 |- doc/ ...
```

In `pipeline1.py`, I have: `import common.common1`. **I corrected this**

In what follows `$[folder]` corresponds to the bash prompt, so `$` stands for normal user and `folder` is the current folder.

When I run `pipeline1.py` as *normal user* (on the remote machine), first I get an error:

```
$[prj/src] python pipeline/pipeline1.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
```

In order to have it working I need to add the current folder to `PYTHONPATH` (that is empty). So

```
$[prj/src] PYTHONPATH=.
$[prj/src] python pipeline/pipeline1.py
```

works.

However, the previous script writes in a disk that requires root access, so the previous command needs to be run with `sudo`. I cannot find a way to run it using sudo:

I tried (after reading, among others, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234758/how-to-use-a-python-virtualenv-with-sudo)):

```
$[prj/src] sudo python pipeline/pipeline1.py
$[prj/src] sudo /path/to/env/bin/python pipeline/pipeline1.py
$[prj/src] sudo -E /path/to/env/bin/python pipeline/pipeline1.py
```

they all fail, all but the first because python cannot find the module `common`. Even if I asked to keep the environment with `-E` (so `PYTHONPATH` should be kept) the import fails. All the other imports from the virtual environment (that occur before the `import common`) do not fail.

In the future I need to give the code to a sys admin that might possibly not have any specific knowledge of python: I cannot ask him to set PYTHONPATH check this, check that.

In this case, how should I organize my code to have the `import common` (or any other module I write) succeed? Do I really need to add `PYTHONPATH=.` every time?

Is there any kind soul willing to help me? Beer after the pandemic is over.

*I made a correction*:

```
import common.common1.py --> common.common1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the start of `pipeline1.py`:

```py
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__), "/.."))
import common.common1
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it depends on the current directory, which is not consistent.  Better, in my opinion, is to append `os.path.realpath( os.path.dirname( __file__ ) + "/..")`.

Comment: I've used this (or close to the same) a few times and eventually found ways to avoid it. flake8 complains about the sys.path.append appearing above another import.

Comment: `os.path.dirname(__file__)` corresponds to `src/pipelines`. Executing your command would mean to add `src` to the path: the folder I am running python from. Shouldn't `src` already be in the path if python is run from `src`? Please notice I am not running `python main_pipeline1.py` from `src/pipelines` but `python pipelines\main_pipeline1.py` from the `src` folder.

Comment: @AntonioSesto, I've found that python modules are weird, and to not depend on where they are run from (unless your really smart). Does it work though?

Comment: It worked with @TimRoberts's command, I think there's a typo in yours since you are joining an "absolute" subfolder ("/..").

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming Linux and also that the Python software to be distributed has the `setup.py`.

Short answer: no, you don't have to modify the `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`

---

- Create a virtual env (say `/opt/myprog`) as usual.
- Activate it and install your package (say `mypkg`) and all its dependencies.
- Put all executable scripts to the `bin` subdirectory of the virtual env and make sure they start with `#!/opt/myprog/bin/python3` shebang line. With correct `setup.py` this will hapen automatically during installation, see [scripts](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts). The scripts will be able to normally import the installed package `import mypkg` or its parts `from mypkg import ...`
- Finally symlink the scripts to a directory in users' `PATH` e.g. to `/usr/local/bin`. This must be done manually and only once unless you add or rename a script.

Projects installed this way can be normally upgraded (with `pip` inside an activated environemnt) and the scripts can be normally invoked from the command line.

Comment: You do not need to assume I am using Linux because I wrote it in the question :-) Thanks, however, your solution is may correct, but too complex for what I am trying to obtain.

Comment: @AntonioSesto You are right about the Linux, sorry. If you find building packages for distribution too complex now, that's OK, but put it on you to-do list to learn it later. For example `git` is much more complex, but for any serious work you need to learn at least the basic level.

Comment: I normally use git, even its advanced features, and I find it incredibly easier than, e.g., understanding python imports :-) In this case I do not understand why the imports fail when I run the pipelines from the src folder since they are all relative to that folder.

Comment: @AntonioSesto I do understand :-). It happened to me several times that I thought I understand the import (finally!), only to find out that it has even more complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the structure and your comments, my guess is that you are not trying
to pip-install this project as a proper Python package. Rather, it is just a
directory with some scripts and modules you want to use. If so, you have at
least a couple of options.

First, don't muck around with `PYTHONPATH` or modifying `sys.path`. That is
almost always a worse approach.

The basic rule for Python importing: the root directory for the purpose of
finding packages is **the directory of the script/file used to invoke Python**.
(Ignoring built-ins and packages that have been formally installed, of course.)

Maybe the easiest solution is to move `common` under `pipelines` (and
optionally make it a
package by creating `__init__.py` inside of it). If you follow the logic
of the basic rule, you'll understand why this works (and it won't
be affected by full-path vs relative-path issues when invoking
python).

```
src/
    pipelines/
        common/
            __init__.py       # Optional for Python 3.3+
            common1.py
            common2.py
        main_pipeline1.py
        main_pipeline2.py
```

Another approach is to create simple runner script at the top level. The runner imports the pipelines, selects
the right one (based command-line argument or some other configuration),
and executes its top-level code (eg, its `main()`). If the pipelines
are not well organized for that type of importing and execution, this
approach is quite a bit harder.

```
src/
    common/
        __init__.py           # Optional
        common1.py
        common2.py
    pipelines/
        __init__.py           # Optional
        main_pipeline1.py
        main_pipeline2.py
    runner.py
```

Separate issue: import modules, not files.

```
import common.common1.py   # No
import common.common1      # Yes
```

Comment: You got the point. This is exactly how the code is organized. There are several runner scripts joining the various "pipelines" in more complex processing. Indeed, each `main_pipeline.py` has a `main()` that is called by the runner scripts or, like in this case, from the usuale `if __name__ == "__main__"` inside of the specific `main_pipeline` when one wants to test a specific pipeline. You said that the root directory corresponds to the folder python is invoked from, but then why doesn't it work when I invoke python in src?

Comment: I made a correction because I was not importing `common.common1.py` but `common.common1`.

Comment: I cannot move common inside of pipelines because there are other modules using common outside of pipelines. The folder structure is more crowded than in the question.

Comment: Are `__init__.py` files needed? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3

Comment: @AntonioSesto I guess not. That change slipped by my radar.