# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Libraries'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have default directory in PyCharm named "Libraries" this is where all my python files are located. When I import files using the following it does not work.

```
from Libraries.my_python_file import my_function
```

But when I use file name without "Libraries." prefix it works

```
from my_python_file import my_function
```

Can anyone help me understand what it is that I am doing wrong?

I have the environment variable path set to the following

- C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\
- C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\

Answer (score 0):

Try adding empty file `__init__.py` in `Libraries` directory.

Comment: it is already there and the contents of the file are empty.

Comment: The OP is using Python3.8, and empty `__init__.py` files are no longer required as of [Python3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37140173/1040092)

Comment: @Wondercricket then why is python complaining ?