# Import utils/config.py from main/daily.py

Tags: python, project

If my project is structured like this:

I have the following folder structure.

```
project
├── main
│   └── daily.py
└── utils
    └── config.py
```

How can I import utils.config from main/daily.py when I run "python project\main\daily.py"?

Comment: Did you try relative import? something like: import ..utils.config

Comment: Yes I already tried, I'm getting either "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" or "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent "

Comment: ah ok. you need to put \_\_init\_\_.py files in folder so python knows it is a package.

Comment: Are you sure I need to do that with Python >3.3? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3