# How to solve "No module named" error in odoo?

Tags: odoo

I have my custom module which has only security folder contains XML file and manifest file then view folder which has xml file.

Do I need to put init file even if I don't have models folder in my module?

My custom module couldn't be installed. It shows error as "no module named" error odoo.

Any help must be appreciatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find anything inside Odoo docs but according to an answer on Odoo forum right [here](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/init-py-python-import-file-17508) - `__init__.py` is always necessary.

I believe it is Python requirement. Odoo modules are also Python packages, and init is required for package discovery.
More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3).