# Importing submodule in a submodule - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to import a submodule withing a seperate submodule using python. Here is my directory structure

[image]

I am trying to do this in process_qc.py

```
from package.database import database

d = database.Database('spark')
print(d.sparkSelect('SHOW DATABASES'))
```

It gives me error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'

Comment: There is no `__init__.py` in the `package` directory.

Comment: There is, right above the test folder

Comment: Ah, I see that now. Are you running `process_qc.py` from inside that script?

Comment: app.py is in the wrong place, it should be in the same directory as the readme

Comment: i am trying to run it directly. Like so: python package/application/process_qc.py

Comment: @AndrewAllaire app.py is just a blank file right now. that's not being used

Comment: You need to call the script from that directory where the readme.md is. If you are calling python process_qc.py from where it is it won't work. But the import should work if it is called by app.py when app.py is in the right placek

Comment: I see. I'll move app.py to the folder outside, and import stuff and try and test.

Comment: Moving the call to app.py and moving it outside of the package folder worked. Thanks both

Comment: @gmdev I don't think you need `__init__.py` any more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3

Comment: You need your working directory to contain `package`, then it will be added to PYTHONPATH and found automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not know where `package` exists when you use an absolute import. This is because Python first looks in the built-in modules and then at directories listed in `sys.path` for the requested import. If the import is not found, the current working directory is prepended to `sys.path`.

To use absolute imports, you should either:

1. Execute the script from outside the `package` directory so that the `package` directory is discoverable from a path listed in `sys.path`.
2. Add the package directory to your `PYTHONPATH`:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH':path/to/package'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try doing this with [relative imports](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/):

```
from ..database import database
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. i was looking for an absolute import method to work as well.

Comment: I added it to the answer! Does that work for you? Edit: woops, I did it wrong. No time do dive deeper into it right now, sorry.