# Why do you need a module called __init__.py to make a folder a package

Tags: python, python-module

I am doing a chapter on modules and packages and my book says that to make a folder a package

> it must also contain a special module called __ init__.py

I recently did some work on classes and I though __ init__ was used to initializes instances of a class, so what is it doing here?

Comment: `__init__` is used as a name for the initialisation method of classes, *and* for the initialisation module of a package…

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't any more. PEP-420 introduced implicit namespace packages that relaxed this particular requirement. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37140173/1126841.

Comment: Yeh, I checked it out. I also tried running the programme without the __init__.py module and it worked fine. My book is just a bit outdated then...