# Python 3.8 error when trying to import code from subfolder

Tags: subdirectory, python-3.8, init

I want to import functions in Python 3.8 from a subfolder. This is what worked for me in earlier versions but does not seem to work now:

Folder structure:

```
/MainProject
  runFile.py 
    /Folder1
      pyscript.py
      __init__.py
```

Run runFile.py from MainProject directory:

```
from Folder1.pyscript    import function
```

I also tried

```
from Folder1 import pyscript1
```

I get the following error:

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Folder1.pyscript'; 'Folder1' is not a package"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `__init__.py`, you should have this

```
# encoding: utf-8

# this is a namespace package
try:
    import pkg_resources
    pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)
except ImportError:
    import pkgutil
    __path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

Comment: Could you please explain why should we do so?

Comment: This does not resolve the problem

Comment: You should read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48804718/6713687