# "ImportError: No module named" in python on Mac

Tags: python, unit-testing, automation

I am creating an automation suite based on python and one of my colleague created a automation base package which we have installed in our Mac. I have **init**.py file in my automation base project which have the import script like this "from automationbase.filename import classname". I am importing this class in my other project but it always gave me *ImportError: No module named automationbase.filename* whenever I try to run the testcases together from test suite, although if I run my Test cases individually then there is no issue. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Could you show us the folder and files organization?

Comment: Did you checked with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3) ?