# Usefulness of having folders (containing python files) without __init__.py file in a python project?

Tags: python, package, structure, project

Is there any case (testing or whatever etc...) or usefulness to have a folder containing python files without the `__init__.py` file?
i.e:

```
   project/
           run.py
           package1/
                   file1.py
                   file2.py
```

instead of:

```
   project/
           run.py
           package1/
                    __init__.py
                    file1.py
                    file2.py
```

I ask this because I have seen some projects with folders (that contain python files) with and without the `__init__.py` file so I was wondering if there is a reason for this to happen. I also have seen some people complaining about Pylance in Visual Code Studio missing importing own modules but adding the `__init__.py` file in the folder containing the module seems to solve that issue (in case you have this issue try this ;) ).

From this thread [Is __init__.py not required for packages in Python 3.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3) and other sources I have seen that there are namespace packages in python that do not have the `__init__.py` file. However if I am not mistaken this only applies when you are creating a folder containing ONLY another folder a not python files.

So from all this my take away message for good practices when doing a python project is:

- add a `__init__.py` file to all folders containing python files
- folders that only contain a folder(s) and no python files should not have the `__init__.py` (this is a namespace package)
- folders that only contain images or other no-python files/documents should not have the `__init__.py`

Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We generally [don't take](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) questions about "best practices" or what you "should" do, only about a) what works; b) what best satisfies some *objective* metric such as performance.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Although best practices is a subjective topic I think it is an important one after all they help avoiding situations where things don't work and make things more maintainable (and meaningful). Stack Overflow being such a big reference for software developers I think I would be nice to have a section dedicated to it.