# Getting ModeulNotFoundError while trying to mock a function in pytest even though the module really exists

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I am working on writing unit tests for my code and I am stuck mocking functions. My code base is similar to the example given below

```
app/
   file/
        core/
             conversion.py
   helper/
          common.py
test/
     file/
          conversion_test.py
```

conversion.py contains

```
class Convertor:
      def __init__(self, client_svc, common_svc):
         self.clientSvc = client_svc
         self.commonSvc = common_svc
      
      def my_function(self, inputs):
          result = self.commonSvc.read(inputs)
          return result
```

common.py contains

```
   class CommonReader:
        def __init__(self, args):
            self.path = args

        def read(self, inputs):
            # Some code
            return results
```

and conversion_test.py contains

```
class testConvertor:
       conv = Convertor(client_svc, common_svc)
       
       def test_my_function(self, mocker):
           mocker.patch('app.file.core.convertion.CommonReader.read',
                     return_value=some_output)
       

          result = self.conv.my_function(inputs)
          assert result == some_result
```

But I am getting the following here

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.file.core.convertion.CommonReader'; 'app.file.core.convertion' is not a package
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: make sure you have __init__.py in all your package folders, and run from root, e.g. with `python -m pytest` from your root directory

Comment: @MichaelDelgado why is it required in the python version is 3.3+

Comment: See this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3