# Class not found when using dynamic import

Tags: python

I am trying to dynamically import a module using the following:

```
def import_plugin(plugin_name):
    src = f'plugins.{plugin_name}.plugin'
    module = __import__(src)
    return getattr(module, 'Plugin')

import_plugin('core')
```

This is the project structure:

- main.py
- plugins

  - core

    - plugin.py - This file contains a class named `Plugin`

I'm getting the error: `module 'plugins' has no attribute 'Plugin'`

Comment: Try adding two empty files`plugins/__init__.py` and `plugins/core/__init__.py`

Comment: @chc That won't help. `module` in this case is the top level folder `plugins` as indicated by the error message. OP needs to do something like `module = __import__(src, fromlist=[None])`, or better yet, use `importlib.import_module`.

Comment: @chc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3

Comment: @Axe319 Yes thank you that was it, I changed it to `__import__(src, fromlist=['Plugin'])`.