# Python modules using Jython

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, jython

I am trying to make some utils for a Python script that run using Jython 2.7.0 (I could update if needed)

My current problem is pretty simple, i can't import/use my module
For a bit of context, my python script is run by the Jython-standalone jar, as a Minecraft mod, so its kinda annoying to even get it to detect the modules

When I first tried to import my module, by putting them all in the same folder, I couldn't import them, so I did:

```
import sys

sys.path.append("C:\Users\<myUser>\Desktop\BotUHC+")

import UHCGame #My Module i want to import

def interact(e):
    UHCGame.setupBaseGame(e)
```

Now, my module doesn't send back any "ImportError module not found", but I can't call that function from UHCGame, because i get the error:

`javax.script.ScriptException: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setupBaseGame' in <script> at line number 9`

Despite it being present in the UHCGame.py file, even VSCode auto completion can detect it.

I wandered inside Jython's docs, and found out that it needs to compile some class before importing them, and for some reason, mine wasn't compiled, so i manually compiled it, and still got the same result.

For more info:

- The script that is run "TestFile.py", is in -> .minecraft/saves/world/customnpc/script/python/
- The module is in "C:\Users<myUser>\Desktop\BotUHC+", as for the compiled version of it

Comment: Try moving your `BotUHC` to `.minecraft/saves/world/customnpc/script/python/` and drop the `sys.path.append` statement

Comment: Another thing... Do you have a [`__init__.py` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48804718/8965861) in the package folder? Try to update the question with a simple scheme of the directory structure of the `BotUHC` package