# Python Azure Function import shared code?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I can't for the life of me figure out why I'm unable to import shared code.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**Directory structure**:

```
azure_functions/
| shared/
| | __init__.py
| | identity_utils.py
| function1/
| | __init__.py
| | function.json
| host.json
| requirements.txt
```

**Not working**:

When using `from shared.identity_utils import get_credential`...

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.function1 <--- Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'identity_utils'.
```

When using `from .shared.identity_utils import get_credential`...

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.function1 <--- Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__app__.function1.shared'.
```

When using `from ..shared.identity_utils import get_credential`...

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.function1 <--- Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'identity_utils'.
```

When using `from .. shared.identity_utils import get_credential`...

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.function1 <--- Result: Failure Exception: Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'identity_utils'. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module.
```

When using `from .. shared import identity_utils`..

- Then when calling the imported function, using `credential = identity_utils.get_credential()`

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.function1 <--- Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'identity_utils'. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module.
```

**Working**:

When using `from shared import get_credential` where `get_credential()` is a user-defined function placed *directly in* `shared/__init__.py` file instead of `shared/identity_utils.py`

From my (naive) perspective, this negates the code organization that shared imports provide...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that module name is correct. if you are deploying it to Azure make sure folder name or file name is not available in `.funcignore` file.

This worked for me.

**#My Directory:**

```
PYTHON/
├──HttpTrigger1/
|   ├── __init__.py
|   └── function.json
├──shared/
|   └── identity_utils.py
├──host.json
├──local.settings.json
├──requirements.txt
```

[image]

**`__init__.py`:**

```py
import logging
from shared.identity_utils import get_data
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    return func.HttpResponse(f"This is the main function. \n\n{get_data()}")
```

**`identity_utils.py`:**

```py
def get_data():
    return "This is from the shared folder identity_utils."
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

```
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5455 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.27.5.21554

[2023-12-12T04:12:39.513Z] Custom packages not in sys path. This should never happen! 
[2023-12-12T04:12:40.770Z] 0.02s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
[2023-12-12T04:12:40.772Z] 0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
[2023-12-12T04:12:40.773Z] 0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
[2023-12-12T04:12:40.774Z] 0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
[2023-12-12T04:12:40.904Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        HttpTrigger1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2023-12-12T04:12:44.965Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=03cfa2d1-848d-4b12-85fd-0468b53a72c2)
[2023-12-12T04:12:45.072Z] Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2023-12-12T04:12:45.144Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=03cfa2d1-848d-4b12-85fd-0468b53a72c2, Duration=200ms)
[2023-12-12T04:12:45.780Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000AAE5F384'.
```

[image]

[image]

**#Azure:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [The Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-configuration#import-behavior) say that `shared` directory needs to have an `__init__.py` file included. This has also been explained in various Github [issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/219#issuecomment-495405654) I've reviewed. I notice you do not have this. Is this a new development in how to import shared code?

Comment: @ericOnline `__init__.py` file not required for `python 3.3+` as it has implicit namespace package. Check this [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3).

Comment: In the GitHub issue link the `Shared_code` folder is inside the function folder. And I checked with similar directory structure, it is throwing error without `__init__.py` file. [image1](https://i.imgur.com/OCGSRW5.png), [error](https://i.imgur.com/moGzAMb.png)

Comment: to import in this type directory structure use this `from .shared.identity_utils import get_data`

Comment: As you can see from the 2nd example in the "**Not working**" section of the original post @VivekVaibhavShandilya, I tried `from .shared.identity_utils import get_credential`. That doesn't import. See the error shown.

Comment: @SeaDude it will only work when the `shared` folder is inside the `function1` folder. OP is not using `shared` folder inside the `function1` folder.

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya, but your `shared` folder is **not** inside the `function1` folder yet you are able to use `from shared.identity_utils import get_data`? I have the project setup the same way, yet the first example shows it failing. I can't figure out what is different between your project and mine except I am using v1 pattern and you are using v2.

Comment: @ericOnline I have also used python V1 model. The error you are getting is when running locally or when deployed to azure. Which python version you are using?

Comment: When testing locally. Python v3.11.

Comment: @ericOnline is your project running inside a virtual environment. My function is running inside `.venv` environment. try creating virtual environment using `python -m venv .venv` and activate using `.venv\Scripts\activate`. then run the command `func host start`